# Select Multiple Table and Row at the same time

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to link these two tables `user_friends` and `users_students` by calling a `SELECT`.

`user_friends` contains:

```
accid  |  user1  |  user2  |
1        mark       leo 
2        leo        john
3        john       mark
```

While `users_student` has the profile's info:

```
studentuniqueid  |  name  |  age  |  address
mark                Mark     20      NYC 
leo                 Leonardo 21      PHL 
john                Johnny   20      OKC
```

Now I want to select all of Mark's Friends and `ORDER` them by `name` (alphabetically based on `users_students`)... Mark could either be in `user1` or `user2` in the `user_friends` so I tried this:

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['myid'];
$sql = "SELECT user_friends.accid,users_student.studentuniqueid FROM user_friends INNER JOIN IN (user_friends.user1,user_friends.user2)=users_student.studentuniqueid WHERE user1 = '$user_id' OR user2 = '$user_id' ORDER BY users_student.name ASC ";
```

But didn't work. How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: so the result you want depending on this data sample is going to be only `leo` ?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I'm not familiar with JOIN IN syntax

Comment: @Accountantم I expect it to be `leo` and `john`